# How can you schedule a test case to run everyday on WamyCloud? (automation QA)

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation

I created a test case that is passing on [Wamy](https://wamy.cloud/), but I'm not sure how to schedule the test case to run every night. For example, here is a test case to test the "Yahoo finance home page" but I can't find a button to schedule it.
[image: WamyCloud Test CaSe]

[image: WamyCloud Test Case passing]